# Here is a break-down graph of operations done in 4-bit integer multiplication.

Tags: graph-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, prime-factorization, integers

[image: 2]

The blue nodes represent the number $b = b_3b_2b_1b_0$, and the green nodes represent the number $a = a_3a_2a_1a_0$.  The yellow nodes are the output bits after multiplying $a \cdot b$.  If $a\cdot b$ would not normally fit in a 4-bit word, then the nodes only represent the lower bits of that multiplication.  Would working with this graph make integer factorization easier?

For example.
Here's the graph supposing that all $c_i$ bits are $1$.  And we've moved up to 5-bit multiplication:
[image]

The other red nodes are immediately deduced to be $1$.  Now what's the minimal set of remaining nodes such that if we knew their bit settings, then we can immediately deduce the rest of the graph?

Comment: Oh wow, that's the _worst_ renderings of multiplication circuits I've seen in a long time. The random jumble almost conceals the fact that they don't work -- in both graphs $c_1$ is created as $a_0a_1+b_0b_1$ whereas it should be $a_0b_1+b_0a_1$. (And I haven't bothered to check the higher bits).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can be absolutely certain that everybody who works in factorization *knows how multiplication works*, and how to wire up a straightforward binary multiplier. In spite of this, factorization is still considered a hard problem -- which ought to answer your question about whether drawing such a network makes factorization easier.

Essentially what you're proposing is to rephrase the factorization problem as a boolean-circuit SAT problem, but SAT is generally believed to be even harder than integer factorization (in the sense that SAT is NP-complete whereas factorization probably isn't). So that wouldn't generally be expected to represent progress.